# Writing a bash function with quotation marks

Tags: macos, bash, function, escaping

I'm trying to write a bash function that uses perl to find and replace characters.  I've written the following function:

```
find_replace() {
 perl -p -i -e "s/$1/$2/g" "$3"

}
```

It is not working right now, I think because $1 and $2 are being escaped by the quotation marks that surround them (which as far as I know, are a part of the perl syntax that needs to be there).

Any tips on how to make this function work (or a better way to write it that avoids this problem)?

EDIT:

Following Barmar's suggestion, here is the output when I attempt to run the function:

```
dholtz$ find_replace \001 , revenue_by_offer_tid
+ find_replace 001 , revenue_by_offer_tid
+ perl -p -i -e ''\''s/001/,/g'\''' revenue_by_offer_tid
++ update_terminal_cwd
++ local 'SEARCH= '
++ local REPLACE=%20
++ local PWD_URL=file://Dave-Mac-2.local/Users/dholtz
++ printf '\e]7;%s\a' file://Dave-Mac-2.local/Users/dholtz
dholtz$ head revenue_by_offer_tid
+ head revenue_by_offer_tid
Friday00228686050.0
Friday00228690410.0
Friday017438366585.040000000000004
Friday017438366591.3200000000000003
Friday017438366600.12
Friday0174383666114.759999999999962
Friday017438371407.440000000000006
Friday0174383815118.599999999999977
Friday017438382221.5600000000000005
Friday017438383663.480000000000002
```

Expected output is:

```
Friday,0,0,22,86860,50.0
Friday,0,0,22,86904,10.0
Friday,0,1,7438,36658,5.040000000000004
Friday,0,1,7438,36659,1.3200000000000003
Friday,0,1,7438,36660,0.12
Friday,0,1,7438,36661,14.759999999999962
Friday,0,1,7438,37140,7.440000000000006
Friday,0,1,7438,38151,18.599999999999977
Friday,0,1,7438,38222,1.5600000000000005
Friday,0,1,7438,38366,3.480000000000002
```

Comment: You don't need to escape quotes in a function.

Comment: I don't see how you expect to get the expected output with the substitution you did. How does replacing `001` with `,` change `Friday002` into `Friday,0,0,2`?

Comment: Barmar - I'm guessing there are SOH characters in that file that just don't show up when it's displayed on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes were preventing the quotes from being processed properly

```
find_replace() {
  perl -p -i -e "s/$1/$2/g" "$3"    
}
```

Comment: Oh weird, I think that was a copy + paste error or something.  I have fixed that (and amended my original post accordingly), but this function still does not behave as it should.

Comment: Please post how you're trying to use it. You can also put `set -x` in the script to see how the commands are being executed.

Comment: Updated original posting accordingly.

Comment: Where are the single quotes and backslashes in `''\''s/001/,/g'\'''` coming from?

Comment: They're not in the function you posted, you must be running something different. I just tried the function I wrote, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I copy and pasted exactly what you provided into my .bash_profile.

Comment: Yes.  I made sure to do that.

Comment: `declare -f find_replace` should display the current definition of the function, does it match what I wrote above?

Comment: `Dave-Mac-2:~ dholtz$ declare -f find_replace
    find_replace () 
    { 
        perl -p -i -e "s/$1/$2/g" "$3"
    }
    Dave-Mac-2:~ dholtz$`

Answer (score 0):

The bash manual tells:

> A non-quoted backslash (\) is the escape character. It preserves the
>   literal value of the next character that follows, ...

So, as we see in the output above, your command

```
find_replace \001 , revenue_by_offer_tid
```

is treated as (\ just unnecessarily preserving the 0)

```
find_replace 001 , revenue_by_offer_tid
```

- not as you wanted. To preserve the backslash, you must quote it *in the command line you enter*, e. g.

```
find_replace \\001 , revenue_by_offer_tid
```